# Guard cannot load bundle/set while spring enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Learning Rails by following Rails tutorial, https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-advanced_testing_setup.

Trying to set up **Guard** for auto test running but I have the following error when I try to run all tests,

There is **NO** problem when I turn spring to `false`.

```
li-xinyang@MachineX FS_RailsSampleApp (master)*$ bundle exec guard
20:06:46 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.4.4 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.9.0!
20:06:46 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp'
[1] guard(main)>
20:06:53 - INFO - Run all
20:06:53 - INFO - Running: all tests
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/FS_RailsSampleApp/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rake:2:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rake:2:in `<main>'
```

I have tried to kill the spring process and explicitly restart the spring server again, but the error is still there.

The code snippet below is my Gemfile and Guardfile,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Guardfile,

```
# Defines the matching rules for Guard.
guard :minitest, spring: true, all_on_start: false do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)/?(.*)_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { 'test' }
  watch('config/routes.rb')    { integration_tests }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.*?)\.rb$}) do |matches|
    "test/models/#{matches[1]}_test.rb"
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*?)_controller\.rb$}) do |matches|
    resource_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/([^/]*?)/.*\.html\.erb$}) do |matches|
    ["test/controllers/#{matches[1]}_controller_test.rb"] +
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*?)_helper\.rb$}) do |matches|
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch('app/views/layouts/application.html.erb') do
    'test/integration/site_layout_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb') do
    integration_tests << 'test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb') do
    ['test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb',
     'test/integration/users_login_test.rb']
  end
  watch('app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb') do
    'test/integration/users_signup_test.rb'
  end
  watch(%r{app/views/users/*}) do
    resource_tests('users') +
    ['test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb']
  end
end

# Returns the integration tests corresponding to the given resource.
def integration_tests(resource = :all)
  if resource == :all
    Dir["test/integration/*"]
  else
    Dir["test/integration/#{resource}_*.rb"]
  end
end

# Returns the controller tests corresponding to the given resource.
def controller_test(resource)
  "test/controllers/#{resource}_controller_test.rb"
end

# Returns all tests for the given resource.
def resource_tests(resource)
  integration_tests(resource) << controller_test(resource)
end
```

Both files above are copy-paste from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the executing line in your Guardfile from:

```
guard :minitest, spring: true, all_on_start: false do
```

to:

```
guard :minitest, cmd: "bundle exec spring rake test" do
```

in order to point Guard to execute the right Spring with the right arguments

Comment: Thank you. @Ivan Zarea error is gone, but when I run `bundle exec spring status` it shows "Spring is not running."